# Can't find any solution or product that'll add one more USB-C port to MacBook Pro13

Tags: usb

Macbook 13 Pro. Two USB-C ports only

- one used for charging
- one used to connect to a monitor
- I need another one for a USB-C to ethernet adapter

Is there a USB-C hub anywhere in existence? I can't find anything on Amazon to my amazement. I need 3 USB-C ports on my MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question will likely elicit opinion-based answers, but what you are looking for is a **Thunderbolt 3 dock**. These can include USB-C, USB 3.0, Thunderbolt 2 and 3 ports, gigabit ethernet, FireWire 800, SD card slots, HDMI, DisplayPort, audio jacks, and so on.

Prices range from a little over $100 to more than $400, depending on what connectors and how many are included. [See this page here to get some ideas](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-thunderbolt-dock/), but you are looking for a Thunderbolt 3 dock.

Comment: Bottom line, Is there a dock like that that would give me 3 USB-C ports? All I've seen with those docks so far is I get the same two USB-C ports duplicated, and adding things I don't need like USB3, HDMI etc. I just need 3 USB-C ports on my mac. It's that simple.

Comment: In my experience, I've never seen a USB-C-only hub. The closest I've seen is USB 3.0 hubs that connect to USB-C ports. This is likely because most people are looking for adaptors still. You could consolidate your connection to a monitor and ethernet with one of these docks, but it sounds like it's not what you are looking for.